# Vector and relative position

Tags: multivariable-calculus

suppose a straight river 0.5km wide flows due east at a constant speed 3km/h.Suppose a boat row at 2km/h from a point A on the south shore to point B,which is k km downstream from the point directly north of point A of the other shore.What direction should you head to cross the river.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to wind up at the point $B$ and that the direction of travel is 
constant.

Let $\theta$ be the angle at which the boat travels with respect to the south shore.

The velocity vector of the boat is
${\bf v}=(3+ 2\cos\theta) {\bf i}+   2(\sin\theta ) {\bf j}$.

To find $\theta$, solve the system of equations: 
$$
(3+ 2\cos\theta)t = k,\quad \text {and}\quad  2(\sin\theta )t =\textstyle{1\over2}
$$
where $t$ is the time it takes for the boat to reach point $B$.